# How to use a class name stored as a data-* attribute as a selector

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I'm working with a small click function that I want to store some data in the HTML5 attribute, but I'm stumped as to how to use the class name that is stored as a selector to run a function on. Here's my HTML with the stored classname:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle=".calendar__event--blue">Click</a>
```

When the element is clicked, I want to hide the '.calendar__event--blue' class. Here's what I've tried:

```
$('.sidebar__mycals--nested a').on('click', function () {
    var elToggle = $(this).data('toggle')
    elToggle.fadeOut()
})
```

But obviously this is returning the data object instead of the class name as a selector, wondering if there's any way to target the element from the data store. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean like:

```
$('.sidebar__mycals--nested a').on('click', function () {
    var elToggle = $(this).data('toggle');
    $("."+elToggle).fadeOut();
})
```

Comment: Ahh okay, that was simple enough. I removed the '.' from the data-* attr and added it in the function, very nice thank you! :)